# SQL script to count X of Y records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to index my records using X of Y count but having some issues. Here is an example:

TableA

```
BOL#  PalletID  Shipper  ColX   ColY   
12    3600      FDX
12    3601      FDX
12    3602      FDX
12    3603      FDX
13    3604      FDX
13    3605      FDX
13    3606      FDX
```

I need a script that will populate ColX and ColY. ColX should be sequential count and break by BOL#. ColY should be the max of ColX break by BOL as well.

Results should look like this:

```
BOL#  PalletID  Shipper  ColX  ColY   
12    3600      FDX       1     4
12    3601      FDX       2     4
12    3602      FDX       3     4
12    3603      FDX       4     4
13    3604      FDX       1     3
13    3605      FDX       2     3
13    3606      FDX       3     3
```

appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for window functions.  For the example you provided:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by bol order by palletid) as colx,
       count(*) over (partition by bol) as coly
from tablea t;
```

Comment: That was a fast turnaround.  You beat me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it using Cross Apply, But any day I will chose Gordan's solution

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by bol order by palletid) as colx,
       cs.coly
from tablea t;
CROSS APPLY 
(SELECT COUNT(1) from tablea where a.bol = b.bol) cs (coly)
```

or use `Correlated Sub-Query`

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by bol order by palletid) as colx,
       (SELECT COUNT(1) from tablea where a.bol = b.bol) as coly
from tablea t;
```